# Instagram API - location search issue with posts

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, google-maps, instagram

I am working with a mashup of two API.
Instagram and Google Maps.

I have it all working and everything but an issue I have is that it doesnt show "up to 20 pictures" around. I dont know why.

Sometimes I get up to 12, sometimes 13, and sometimes only 3 (depending on the distance I choose in the query.

When I dont use any distance in the query I can get up to 12 and when I put distance=1000 i get like 8 pictures, but when I put distance=2000 or even more 3000 I can get all from 1-3 pics at most.

Do any of you have any idea how i can fix that issue?
Here is a bit of the code that does that function. I know there is more than 20 pictures to show in this area but I dont know why it doesnt show them. I picture I posted yesterday insnt in there and it shows right know only 10 posts made in that area.

```
    function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=59.24642059999999&lng=18.0613027&distance=1000&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_CODE", 
dataType: 'jsonp', 
cache: false });
        }

var promise = getData();
promise.done(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $(".myLocation").append("<li><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url + "'></img>" 
                                              + "<p class='thumblikes'><img src='img/likeicon.png'></img>" + data.data[i].likes.count + "</p>" 
                                              + "</li>");
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your URL in the question looks wrong: `url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=59.24642059999999&lng=18.0613027&distance=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_CODE",`, MY_ACCESS_TOKEN doesn't seem like a valid "distance".

Comment: Oh.. I forgot to put that in the code here. Sorry. It was distance=1000 or distance=5000.. But with or without distance i still dont get 20 pics... @geocodezip

Answer (score 0):

Instagram returns maximum of 20 photos per API call, Instagram does not have pagination for this API call, so you have use the `max_timestamp` API url param to get the next 20 photos.

After the first API call, get data.created_time of the last photo, make API call with this value for `max_timestamp=` in API URL, this will return the next 20 photos and so on...

Here is an implementation of location search with pagination: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map